# Connection was refused by other side: 111: Connection refused. when using Scrapy Crawlera in a linux server

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, screen-scraping, crawlera

Scrapy Crawlera was working just well in my Windows machine, but it gets error 111 when I run it in my linux server. Why is that?

When I use curl, I got this error:
`curl: (7) Failed connect to proxy.crawlera.com:8010; Connection refused`

Comment: Try to switch to HTTPS or HTTP whatever you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out when dealing with ports, CPanel (or maybe Linux?) blocks ports by default if it is not whitelisted in the firewall. I opened it via WHM since I use CPanel, and everything works fine now.

Answer (score -1):

It has most likely nothing to do with Windows or Linux, but with the *user-agent* of Scrapy. Try doing sth. like this in `settings.py`:

```
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.7
```

Comment: Then why does it work in Windows? And I already use Scrapy Fake User Agent which sets random user agents automatically

Comment: @AminahNuraini `proxy.crawlera.com` is a proxy server, `user agent` should definitely not be the problem. I guess it just depends on `crawlera` itself. Maybe they limit your connection to one or some other mechanism. Try to wait a while or ask them for help.